# How would you model this led strip?

Tags: bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I'm quite new with blender, so this might be a stupid question.

I want to model and render something like the attached image, but I'm not able to keep the light normal to the helix curve. It keeps twisting in a weird way.

I tried with the screw modifier and with the curve modifier and I was not able to model it.

And how would you add the straight end to the strip?

How would you do it?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here’s one way to do it:

1. Start with a profile mesh for the strip:

   [image]
2. Add a Screw modifier with 0° for the angle and a suitable number of iterations:

   [image]
3. Add an Archemedian Spiral curve with the appropriate parameters to get the rough shape, and in the curve properties, set the Twist Method to Z-Up.

   [image]
4. Add a Curve modifier to the strip object with the Deform Axis set to Z:

   [image]

The trickiest parts of this seem to be getting the normals correct on the extruded mesh produced by the Screw modifier and getting the twist right on the curve. Checking the Calculate Order box in the Screw modifier options seemed to help with the normals, and using the Z-Up twist method for the curve produced the right twisting.

[image]